# __call, __callStatic and calling scope in PHP

Tags: php

I recently read about calling scope and scope resolution operator (::) in PHP. There are two variations: instance calling and statical calling. Consider the folowing listeng:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function __call($method, $parameters) {
        echo "I'm the __call() magic method".PHP_EOL;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters) {
        echo "I'm the __callStatic() magic method".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function bar() {
        A::foo();
    }
}

class C {
    public function bar() {
        A::foo();
    }
}

A::foo();
(new A)->foo();

B::bar();
(new B)->bar();

C::bar();
(new C)->bar();
```

The result of execution (PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2) is:

```
I'm the __callStatic() magic method
I'm the __call() magic method
I'm the __callStatic() magic method
I'm the __call() magic method
I'm the __callStatic() magic method
I'm the __callStatic() magic method
```

I don't understand why for `(new C)->bar();` execute `__callStatic()` of `A`? Instance calling should made in the context of bar() method, isn't it? Is it feature of PHP?

Addition1:

Moreover, if I don't use magic methods and do explicitly call, everything works as expected:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "I'm the foo() method of A class".PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Current class of $this is '.get_class($this).PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Called class is '.get_called_class().PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class B {
    public function bar() {
        A::foo();
    }
}

(new B)->bar();
```

Result for this:

```
I'm the foo() method of A class
Current class of $this is B
Called class is B
```

Comment: I'm more interested in why `C::bar();` didn't throw an error.

Comment: Why? I think that it corrects in this case.

Comment: [It's not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with). And likely threw an `E_STRICT`.

Comment: Hm, from my php.ini: `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes, you are right. I must use E_STRICT constant in error_reporting in development, I forget it:)

Comment: `B::bar()` should return give you some error as well

Answer (score 3):

In the `bar()` method in `C`, you have `A::foo();`:

```
public function bar() {
    A::foo();
}
```

As this method is neither creating an instance of `A`, nor does `C` extend `A`, the `::` operator is being treated as a static-operator attempting to call a static method `A::foo()`. Because `foo()` isn't defined on `A`, it's falling-back to the `__callStatic()` method.

If you want it to call the non-static method without extending `A`, you'll have to create an instance of `A`:

```
class C {
    public function bar() {
        $aInstance = new A();
        $aInstance->foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: `::` don't always mean statical call. It depends on calling scope. For `(new B)->bar();` execute `bar()` method of `B` class and than `A::foo()` and in this case made `__callStatic()`, because it is instance calling scope.

Comment: @vasayxtx Sorry, I guess it's bad wording on my part. I meant that in the context of C.bar(), it's being used as a `static` operator. Let me re-word, hopefully I can make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in that case we have no instance of `A` class. 
Notice that

```
 class B extends A
```

So `new B` gives us access to nonstatic version of `A->foo`.

Class `C` does not extend `A` so only static methods of `A` are available.

Comment: Ok, I get it. It wasn't enough obvious, at least for me.

Comment: Don't worry. This stuff can get tricky and requires some attention so as not to overlook some minor, yet important detail.

Comment: "Class C does not extend A so only static methods of A are available."
Can I read about it in the manual?

Comment: Would you see my addition1 and explain me why it works as expected. Is your saing applicable only to magic method __call()?