# Call __call instead of __callstatic in same class, not if call another class

Tags: php, static, call, static-methods

I have a question about a strange comportement.

Look at this code :

```
class User
{
    public function can($name) {
        return call_user_func(array($name, 'test'));
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        return 'User::__callStatic';
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        return 'User::__call';
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        return 'Foo::__callStatic';
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        return 'Foo::__call?';
    }
}

$u = new User();
var_dump($u->can('User'));
var_dump($u->can('Foo'));
```

The results of the first var dump is :
   "User::__call"
And the second :
   "Foo::__callStatic"

Why the first one don't call the function __callStatic ?

PS : I look at other topics, but not found an explaination.

Thanks

Comment: this code works: https://3v4l.org/E1gKl

Comment: @Edwin I know :) This is not my question, I expect to have "User::__callStatic" for the first var dump

Comment: I posted in response to other comments that now are deleted

Comment: A good question about a gray area of the PHP OOP.

Comment: somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487874/call-callstatic-and-calling-scope-in-php?rq=1 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139042/why-does-php-prefer-call-to-callstatic?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

This is just a problem of scope when you call the `call_user_func`.

When you first call the `can` function you are in the class `User` context and it will take `__call`. In the second call your context is from outside the second class, so therefore it takes the `__callStatic`. Check [callback manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) and [call-user-func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

For instance [code](https://3v4l.org/qCUWI):

```
<?php

class User
{
    public function can($name) {
        return call_user_func(array($name, 'test'));
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        return 'User::__callStatic';
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        return 'User::__call';
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public function can($name) {
        return call_user_func(array($name, 'test'));
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $args) {
        return 'Foo::__callStatic';
    }

    public function __call($name, $args) {
        return 'Foo::__call?';
    }
}

    function can($name) {
        return call_user_func(array($name, 'test'));
}

$u = new User();
$f = new Foo();
var_dump($u->can('User'));
var_dump($u->can('Foo'));
var_dump($f->can('User'));
var_dump($f->can('Foo'));
var_dump(can('User'));
var_dump(can('Foo'));
```

will return:

```
string(12) "User::__call" 
string(17) "Foo::__callStatic" 
string(18) "User::__callStatic" 
string(12) "Foo::__call?"
string(18) "User::__callStatic"
string(17) "Foo::__callStatic"
```

Comment: Scope is the wrong word, *context* is what you're looking for. The question then though is why PHP decides that `call_user_func(['User', ...])` in a `User` context is an instance call, while in another context it's static.

Comment: yes context is better. If you will made the `can` function static it would return the `__callStatic`, so I think php it's trying to find first the functions on the same level (if this makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both of you.

Yes this is due to *context* , is that a bug of PHP (fix in the later version, not in 7.2, so... ;) ) or is it just a strange comportement.

@Edwin I know if I transform the function `can()` to static, it will work, but I doesnt want to. To resolve the "problem", I call the function `__callStatic()` in my function `can()` only in the case of calling self class :

`if($name instanceof User)
    return self::__callStatic($functionName, $args);`