# Method static by default?

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

I just recently discovered this strange behavior in my project.

I have a method that I accidentally defined as just a function (it's supposed to be `public static`), and then I called this method statically – and it still worked! Why is this?

```
class C {
   function n() {
      ...
   }
}

$y = C::n();  // This works, method is performed as intended, and without errors
```

By the way, I am using version 5.4.

Comment: Have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with And also you might even see a warning if you have strict reporting on

Comment: Any accessible method can be called in a static context, only a warning will be raised and obviously any reference to `$this` will cause an error.

Comment: @AlexP I'm not getting any warnings at all =/