# Purpose of Static Class Functions in PHP

Tags: php, static, static-methods

I thought that the use of the `static` keyword in the declaration of a class function meant that you could call the function without an instance of the class using the scope resolution operator (`::`).

For example:

```
class Foo
{
    public static function static_function() {
        return 'x';
    }
    public function non_static_function() {
        return 'y';
    }
}

// to call static_function:
echo Foo::static_function();

// to call non_static_function:
$foo = new Foo();
echo $foo->non_static_function();
```

The PHP.net documentation on [`static`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) seems to support this idea.

I came across some code yesterday that someone had wrote accessing class functions using the scope resolution operator that had NOT been defined with the static keyword. I was surprised and confused to see this worked.

Given my class defined above, `Foo`, it turns out you can actually do:

```
echo Foo::static_function();
echo Foo::non_static_function();
```

Resulting in output `xy` without generating any errors or warnings.

If you can access non-static class functions without the `static` keyword, what is the point in it?

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) "Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning."

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Resulting in output xy without generating any errors or warnings.

**No way**. The error reporting must have been turned off on that environment. That would have definitely produced a `Strict Standards` warning notice.

Comment: So it does. I learnt something new, but not what I initially thought - `E_ALL` does not include `E_STRICT` before 5.4. I'll accept this as the answer when the time limit is reached.

Comment: That is correct. FYI the [**changelog**](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#refsect1-function.error-reporting-changelog)