# Call to a non static method with out creating an object works fine in PHP

Tags: php, function, scope-resolution

I am doing a PHP tutorial and I found this code

```
Class Insurance
{
   function clsName()
   {
      echo get_class($this)."\n";
   }
}


$cl = new Insurance();
$cl->clsName();
Insurance::clsName();
```

here `function clsName()` is accessed without creating an instance of `Insuarance`

```
Insurance::clsName();
```

But from the definition

> The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in
>   simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to
>   static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.
>
> When referencing these items from outside the class definition, use
>   the name of the class.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

I searched in web but coul not find a good explanation why this code is working? 
please explain.

Comment: Because that is how php should behave ? That's the point of a static method/property. I don't understand what you want now?

Comment: @Rizier123 function clsName() is not a static method

Comment: This shouldn't work though, because the `clsName()` method contains an explicit reference to `$this`, which doesn't exist in a static context

Comment: Error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` == `Strict Standards: Non-static method Insurance::clsName() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sandbox\index.php on line 30

Notice: Undefined variable: this in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sandbox\index.php on line 23`

Comment: @Rizier123 It's not a static method. This is a legit question.

Comment: I checked the code in http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Static access to non-static methods used to work without problem (except when the methods referenced $this) but that has been tightened up in more recent versions of PHP

Comment: http://3v4l.org/TTd30

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya You get almost in every version a php warning/error: http://3v4l.org/F1u1q

Comment: for all the fancy stuff around them, methods are still just functions, and you can call them however/wherever you want. But that doesn't mean they'll work CORRECTLY. e.g. calling your method will produce errors because `$this` is not available when called statically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with

Answer (score 1):

When I run it with error reporting E_ALL :

```
Insurance
<br />
<b>Strict Standards</b>:  Non-static method Insurance::clsName() should not be called statically in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: this in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
Insurance
```

Now the question is why it still working ? as you can see, "Insurance" was displayed.

When you do `echo get_class($this)."\n";` when you call in a static context, PHP will run it like `echo get_class(null)."\n";`.

And if you read the behavior of `get_class` http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php, The class is recognized because the function was call inside the class.