# Usage of $this and self in object oriented PHP

Tags: php, oop

I know that inside a class, `$this` is used to refer to the current object and `self` is used to refer to the current class. For example:

```
class My_Class {

    function start1() {
        $var = self::hello();

        echo $var;
    }

    function start2() {

        $var = $this->hello();

        echo $var;
    }

    function hello() {
        return 'Hello';
    }
}

$obj = new My_Class;
$obj->start1(); // Hello
$obj->start2(); // Hello
```

In my example, both `$this->hello()` and `self::hello()` appear to do the exact same thing. Can anyone give an example of when I should use `$this` and when I should use `self`?

Comment: @Rizier123 that is not accurate, for static the better is to use the word static, self is only helpful to avoid overwrites of methods. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: The question has been reopened.

Comment: You're welcome Henry.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);`

Comment: dpue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3754786/3933332 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/151969/3933332 ?

Answer (score 1):

`$this` cannot be used on static functions.

And `$this` needs an instantiated object.

```
class example
{
    public static $mystring ;
    public $anotherString;

    //non-static functions (calling static and non-static variables)
    public function regularFunction() { echo $this->anotherString; } 
    public function regularFnUsingStaticVar() { echo self::$mystring ; }

    //static functions (calling static functions and variables)
    public static function anotherStatFn() { self::staticFunction(); }
    public static function staticFunction() { echo self::$mystring ; }
}

// using static vars and functions
example::$mystring = "Hello World!";
example::staticFunction();           /* Hello World! */

// using non-static vars and functions
$obj = new example();
$obj->anotherString = "Hello World!";
$obj->regularFunction();             /* Hello World! */
```

Comment: That should be an comment