# PHP Static and Normal Functions Calling

Tags: oop, php, static-methods

Can someone explain how these line of code are working

```
class DemoStatic {
  function normalFunction() {
    echo "This is the normal function";
  }
  static function staticFunction() {
    echo "This is the static function";
  }
}
$classObj = new DemoStatic();
```

> `DemoStatic::normalFunction();` vs. `$classObj->normalFunction();`

and

> `DemoStatic::staticFunction();` vs. `$classObj->staticFunction();`

And the output is as below

> This is the normal function
>
> This is the normal function
>
> This is the static function
>
> This is the static function

Now I really don't understand that how come a normal function is accessible via `::` Operator and static function is called using the class object.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: I got warning while running `DemoStatic::normalFunction();` `Strict standards: Non-static method DemoStatic::normalFunction() should not be called statically`. Do you have your warnings turned on?

Comment: It is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with

Comment: `::` is for calling a (static) method of a class. `->` is for calling a method on an instantiated object. If you don't know what an instantiated object is and how it's useful, you need to learn a bit more about the basics of OOP. A static class method is essentially just a function; only that it's part of a class and not a global function.

Comment: If your method has no reference to `$this` then you can call it statically even if it's not explicitly declared as such. Note that if you add `$this` to your staticFunction, you'll get a fatal.

Comment: @Med I have warnings turned on in my Xampp setup.