# Why can I call non-static function without declaring the class object?

Tags: php, apache, oop, model-view-controller, symfony1

I am using Symfony 1.0, and I have this `MyClassInc.class.php` in my `project/lib` folder

```
class MyClassInc {
  public function validateFunction ($params) {
    // my codes
  }
  static function testFunction ($params){
    // my codes
  }
}
```

Then, my action `actions.class.php` in my `project/apps/myapps/modules/actions`.

```
class inventoryCycleCountActions extends sfActions
{
  public function validateOutstandingTransaction () {
    $res0 = MyClassInc :: validateFunction($param); // It works
    $res1 = MyClassInc :: testFunction($param); // It works
    $myClass = new MyClassInc();
    $res2 = $myClass->validateFunction($param); // still works
    $res3 = $myClass->testFunction($param); // still works, da hell?
  }
}
```

I tried to clear my cache folder to do re-test, but it seems that all of those work just fine.

**Question:**
So.. WHY? and which one should I use? Does it have any effect with performance or anything?

**Update 1:**

```
class MyClassInc {
  public function isProductValidated ($product){
    return true;
  }
  public function validateFunction ($params) {
    // IF, I call by using "$res0".. Throws error
    //
    $this->isProductInLoadPlans($product);
  }
}
```

If I call validateFunction via ***$res0***, it will throw this error:

> sfException: Call to undefined method
>   inventoryCycleCountActions::isProductValidated.

**And**, if I call it via ***$res2***, it works just fine.

Since, I am currently using ***$res0*** and so I have to call that method like this instead.

> MyClassInc :: isProductValidated ($product)

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with), basically, PHP will warn you (if you have error reporting enabled). You won't have access to any instance variables if you call a non-static function statically however. So if you try to use any variables that only apply to an object (i.e instance variables), you'll get a fatal error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dave.. The thread that u refer is pretty useful and thanks to that Im more confused on how I should implement this class of mine. Is there any downside for calling non static function with ::?

Comment: As far as I can see, there's only a warning generated by PHP when you call an instance method statically. If you call a static method objectively there's no error. So you can always get away with `->`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only real difference between `::` and `->` is how `$this` is handled. With `::` the function will have `$this` as it was defined in the caller's scope:

```
class A {

  public function foo() {
    A::bar();
    A::foobar();
  }

  static private function bar() {
     // $this here is the instance of A
  }

  static public function foobar() {
    // Here you can have anything in $this (including NULL)
  }
}

$a = new A;
$a->foo();
$a->foobar(); // $this == $a but bad style
A::foobar(); // $this == NULL
```

When you want to use an instance method, you should use `->` because that would resolve instance methods properly (including inheritance). `::` will always call the method of the specified class.

I believe there is effort made now to enforce calling static methods only as statically and dynamic methods only dynamically to avoid the confusion.

Comment: So, any recommendation which i should go for with?

Comment: If your function is static, use ::. If you function is not static, use ->.