# How to call a non static method using static keyword?

Tags: php, oop, php-5.5

I am just checking the OOPs static/non-static concept and found something strange.

I have heard that static method's output can be get by using static keyword with resolution operator(::) . But In my program I am getting non static method's value using static keyword. Can any one explain the program? I am getting confused.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class parentclass
{
    protected function sum()
    {
        return 145;
    }
}

class childclass extends parentclass
{
    protected function sum()
    {
        return 125;
    }
}

class grandchild extends childclass
{
    function sum()
    {
        return 100;
    }

    function __construct()
    {
        echo static::sum(); // 100 as output but how
    }
}

$obj = new grandchild(); 
?>
```

Besides this If I am making function sum() of childclass as static like

```
class childclass extends parentclass
{
   protected static function sum()
   {
    return 125;
   }
 }
```

then also it is giving fatal error as following:

**Fatal error: Cannot make non static method parentclass::sum() static in class childclass**

But why I am not calling that function.

Comment: Running it here: https://3v4l.org/rfQSe shown 100...

Comment: yes actually I have edited the function name now. it is now sum()

Comment: If you are not absolutely sure when statics are useful, try to avoid them. In your example, it does not make sense to use static.

Comment: I am just trying to get the knowledge and the cause why it is giving output as 100. I  mean sum() is non static and I am calling using static:: resolution operator. If you know the reason then please let me know @DanFromGermany

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with

Comment: @DarkBee I have edited my question. there is not only question of static and non static.. I am getting fatal error If I am making parent class function as static.

Comment: What are you expecting? `100`? `125`? `145`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a function statically, even if it is not declared as `static`, as long as you don't reference `$this` inside it.

That is why the original code works.

You cannot, however, change the signature of an inherited method.

> Fatal error: Cannot make non static method parentclass::sum() static
>   in class childclass

When you declare `protected static function sum()` in `childclass`, you are changing the signature of the inherited method from `parentclass` which is not specifically declared `static`.

Bottomline, you are trying to use some PHP quirks that I would recommend against. Yes, they work, but that doesn't mean you should use them.

Stick to a strict style of coding. Write separate methods for static and instance use and call them as intended.

Comment: I was just checking oops concept. It is not related to my any project.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `static` as a [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). But what you heard about was rather

```
class Foo
{
  static function bar() {}
}

$baz = Foo::bar();
```

Comment: yeah, just follow the link and read the article on it. You might then understand how `self` and `static` work and maybe even why they are different.

Comment: Yes dear I know the difference between self and static keywords, I know the concept of late static binding. static keyword is used for late static binding but here is different concept.

Comment: It also makes a difference whether you call a static method outside of or inside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

I think to understand late static bindings a bit better you could write a variation of your code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class parentclass
{
    protected function sum()
    {
        return 145;
    }

    public function do_the_math()
    {
        printf('Static sum: %d, Self sum: %d', 
            static::sum(), 
            self::sum());
    }
}

class childclass extends parentclass
{
    protected function sum()
    {
        return 125;
    }
}

class grandchild extends childclass
{
    function sum()
    {
        return 100;
    }
}

$obj = new grandchild(); 
$obj->do_the_math();
```

Output:

```
Static sum: 100, Self sum: 145
```