# $this getting unknown property yii console

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I need to access a property of a class (which is a Yii2 Model), but when i refer to $this->expires_on inside a function of that class called with this code:

```
$int::createNextDate();
```

($int is a loaded yii model)

i get this error:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Getting unknown property: app\commands\DailyCronController::expires_on'
```

So basically php looks for the property inside the controller.
How can i access that model's property instead?

Edit: here's the full code

this is part of the controller used by the command line

```
        $assistanceTasks = \app\models\AssistanceTask::find()->all();
        foreach($assistanceTasks as $task){
            $task::createNextDate();
        }
```

This is the function inside the model AssistanceTask

```
class AssistanceTask extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
...
public function createNextDate(){

    if(!$this->expires_on){
        return "Error....";
    }
```

But apparently there's a problem with "$this"

FINAL EDIT:
The problem, as pointed by Patryk, is that i used

```
$int::createNextDate();
```

instead of

```
$int->createNextDate();
```

so the function was called as if it was a static function.

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not trying to call `expires_on` not on Model but on `DailyCronController`

Comment: I understood that, but how do i call expires_on on Model?

Comment: Why do You call non static method with `::`? Use  `$task->createNextDate();` insead. Then You should get proper object in `$this` variable

Comment: Thank you. I feel dumb.
That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a populated model available then it should be as easy as

```
$model->expires_on;
```

or in your case

```
$int->expires_on;
```

However without seeing the whole code its really hard to say.

Comment: i updated the post. Anyway, the code is inside a model function, and i want to be able to recall it on a loaded model inside a controller. But while i can do it with normal controller actions, i can't do the same from the command line.

Comment: You can't use $this with static functions. You need to instantiate the class or pass the expires_on to the static function @dgtal

Comment: But the function is not static (or am i wrong?), it even works from any other controller

Comment: But you are calling it as static... Take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754786/calling-non-static-method-with